# Is there any possible benefit to SPECIALIZE a free type variable?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

I think parametricity implies it can *never* help to specialize a free type variable (i.e. one with no class constraints), like a function `:: Maybe a -> Bool`. Are there any cases in the context of ghc where this might actually help that I'm missing?

Comment: Hm. Perhaps for example a specialized `id :: Int -> Int` could be inlined into a place that currently has `Int#`s, and the wrapping and unwrapping of the boxed `Int` could be elided as a result. Not sure about that, though; perhaps the unspecialized `id` could also have that happen...?

Comment: Also: GHC supports arbitrary rewrite rules. You could almost certainly set things up so that a specialized version triggers a rewrite but the unspecialized version doesn't. That's pretty perverse, though; I wouldn't expect it to come up in any sane code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Partial answer, but I'd like to share anyway.)

I tried to specialize a GADT-eliminating function, to see how GHC handles it. Why? Well, it sounded as a crazy way to get around parametricity with only unconstrained variables, and I was curious.

```
data T a where
   A :: Int -> T Int
   B :: String -> T String

{-# SPECIALIZE foo :: T Int -> Int #-}
foo :: T a -> Int
foo (A i) = i
foo (B s) = length s
```

The compiler slightly complained about this:

```
warning: SPECIALISE pragma for non-overloaded function `foo'
|
| {-# SPECIALIZE foo :: T Int -> Int #-}
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Still, the generated Core showed what I hoped to see: the specialized form.

```
foo :: forall a. T a -> Int
foo
  = \ (@a_aPp) (ds_dZc :: T a_aPp) ->
      case ds_dZc of {
        A co_aPq [Dmd=A] i_auj -> i_auj;
        B co_aPs [Dmd=A] s_auk ->
          case GHC.List.$wlenAcc @Char s_auk 0# of ww2_a1Ld { __DEFAULT ->
          GHC.Types.I# ww2_a1Ld
          }
      }

Main.foo_$sfoo :: T Int -> Int
Main.foo_$sfoo
  = \ (ds_dZc :: T Int) ->
      case ds_dZc of { A co_aPq [Dmd=A] i_auj -> i_auj }

------ Local rules for imported ids --------
"SPEC foo" forall. foo @Int = Main.foo_$sfoo
```

Is this useful? I don't know. Is this a true optimization? Maybe. (Perhaps we should look at the assembly to answer that.)

Still, some rewriting rule is being generated pointing to simplified code, so this might potentially turn trigger some optimization in a more serious program. Hard to tell with only the above evidence, but I wouldn't dismiss the possibility.

I'd answer "can the specialization of an unconstrained type variable be of any use, at least in some specific contexts?" with "probably".

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I also didn't realize that a warning was emitted, which is useful information as well (that the conventional wisdom is this is not a useful thing to do)